# Akamai - CDN Cache and no browser cache

Tags: caching, cdn, akamai

For **some files** we want akamai to cache the files and but prevent browser form caching the resources, so as per their post I added following header:

```
<add name="Edge-control" value="!no-store,max-age=365d,downstream-ttl=0" />
```

It is working but now the local proxy has started caching the resources which defeats the purpose.

Adding **private** to the downstream header should most probably fix the issue, but I couldn't find the syntax for same. Something like:

```
<add name="Edge-control" value="!no-store,max-age=365d,downstream-ttl=0,private" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you needed not add these in code. This can be configured in akamai property manager where you can specify which files shouldn't be cached in downstream and make it private too.